# Flutter data transfer with back button

Tags: flutter, navigation

I have one problem.

In my project there are three screens (Screen A,  B and C ).
My First Screen is A and I have pushed B on A.
After that I have pushReplaced C.
Now I want to send data from C to A on POP Screen.
How can I achieve this.

I have try to wait on Screen A for the Screen B to send data.
But when I pushReplace B to C, the waiting on screen a overed.

Comment: try to use `WillPopScope` , or another option is by using `onSave` function

Comment: Google. Follow official docs https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/returning-data

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to achieve what you want

Page A to Page B:

```
  onPressed: (){
      Navigator.push(context,  MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => SecondPage(),
      )).then((value) => print(value));
    },
```

Page B to Page C:

here page B gets removed by using pushReplacement

```
   onPressed: (){
       Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => const ThirdPage(),
          )).then((value){
      Navigator.pop(context,value);
      });
    },
```

Page C to Page A:

```
    onPressed: (){
      Navigator.of(context).pop("Hello From:Third Page");
    },
```

so your

```
      print(value)
```

will print  "Hello World:Third Page"

**Hope this helps you**

First Page

```
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
            const FirstPage({super.key, required this.title});
            final String title;
          
            @override
            State<FirstPage> createState() => _FirstPageState();
          }
          
          class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
            @override
            Widget build(BuildContext context) {
             return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text(widget.title),
                ),
                body: Center(
                 child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children:const <Widget>[
                       Text(
                        'First Page:',
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.push(context,  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) =>SecondPage(),
                    )).then((value) => print(value));
                  },
          
                ),
              );
            }
          }
```

Second Page

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
              const SecondPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
            
              @override
              State<SecondPage> createState() => _SecondPageState();
            }
            
            class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    title:const Text("Second Page"),
                  ),
                  body: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children:const <Widget>[
                         Text(
                          'Second Page:',
                        ),
            
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                       Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => const ThirdPage(),
          )).then((value){
      Navigator.pop(context,value);
      });
                    },
            
                  ),
                );
              }
            }
```

Third page

```
  class ThirdPage extends StatefulWidget {
          const ThirdPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
        
          @override
          State<ThirdPage> createState() => _ThirdPageState();
        }
        
        class _ThirdPageState extends State<ThirdPage> {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title:const Text("Third Page"),
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children:const <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Third Page:',
                    ),
        
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.of(context).pop("Hello World:Third Page");
                },
        
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: I have tried , This is not working.   after execution of this   onPressed: (){
       Navigator.pushReplacement(context,  MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => ThirdPage(),
      ));
    },            on the A Screen got null

Comment: bro it's working for me, please check code properly and try again

Comment: No boss its not working . can you show me complete code.

Comment: This updated code also printing null     after the execution of  Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => const ThirdPage(),
              ));   code

Comment: sorry brother, i copy wrong class Updated code for second class...............................
 Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => const ThirdPage(),
              )).then((value){
          Navigator.pop(context,value);
          });

Comment: you can try this updated code I have tested in my system

Comment: This code is working but there is a catch , In the second page you have used push instead of pushReplancement

Comment: Yes, it won't matter if you want to get to the first page again.

Comment: we can not transfer data without any base second page is the base for third page,
else you will have to use Observable variable to keep checking changes